# How to get item from listView onItemClick in android?

Tags: android, android-listview, onitemclicklistener

I'm working on an app and in that app I've created a custom listview. I am populating the listView from an API call.Now on the click of a perticular list item i want to get the data which is shown on that index.
What shall i change in the below code

```
  vehicle_select_listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            ImageView selectedImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

           selectedImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.simplecheck);
           String str =  parent.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "  " + str , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Please help. Thank you

Comment: what getting in Toast message?

Comment: vehicledetails@2ab.. some random value after @

Comment: what are you returning on  @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    } base adapter. You can show as how you implemented this

Answer (score 7):

Simple as that. `parent.getItemAtPosition(position);`

Comment: I tried that it returns the same thing vehicle details@random value

Comment: That's becouse it returns the object you've set in your adapter. If you want a specific field of the Object, you should use `parent.getItemAtPosition(position).getYourObjectField()`.

Comment: sorry but i didn't get you.. can i paste the code here?

Answer (score 3):

```
parent.getAdapter().getItem(position)
```

this code give an object. You must cast it to your object type. If you use toString() method, it will give you it pointer address(if object dont have custom toString() method.) So you can use that;

```
CustomObject obj = (CustomObject)parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
```

Note : CustomObject is which you give your listview as adapter in list type.

Answer (score 2):

Here how I got item

```
    mListview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TarifeFavorite clickedObj = (TarifeFavorite) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Intent intentToDetay = new Intent(getActivity(), TarifeDetay.class);
            intentToDetay.putExtra("tarife_name",clickedObj.getName());
            startActivity(intentToDetay);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `parent.getItemAtPosition(position);`, it will return an Object (the model used in your adapter).

To get some field from your Object don't call `Object.toString();` it will return the object reference not the value that you're looking for. Use `Object.yourField;` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use the position textview refernce to get the value

```
   TextView tv= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPopUpItem);
        String str= tv.getText().toString();
```